# Git on Visual Studio shows files from another branch

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, git-branch

I have done the following test on Visual Studio 2017:

1)
Created new repo with master branch:

[image]

It just has a gitginore file:

[image]

2) Created Branch1 with file1:

[image]

[image]

3) Checkout master branch again, and opened 'Show folder view':

[image]

[image]

Why on earth am I seeing file1 in master branch?

[image]

Comment: Did you commit File1 to Branch1? The behavior you are describing is expected if you did not commit this file to the branch. In its current state, File1 is an uncommitted change and will remain as such when you change branches assuming there is not a conflicting change on the branch you are changing to.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I might have missed committing it after all. I am transitioning from using command line git (for java) to Azure Devops 'git' Repos on Visual Studio and was frustrated for seeing that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both client side(Visual Studio) and server side(Azure DevOps) are **standard implementations** of Git.

Just as comment mentioned, this is the expired behavior in Git.

The created files(file1) are not put in the repository until you add and commit them.

If you switch back to your Branch1 branch and **commit** the file, then it won't appear on the master branch any more.

Comment: What behavior was expired? There were several comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you move between branches but don't want to commit, just stash your changes.

It will clean up your environment, so that when you move to another branch nothing will be left behind. You will have a clean environment.

When you move back to the previous branch you can un-stash.

If you are familiar with TFS, a stash is such like a shelveset.

Take a look at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working
>   directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working
>   directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts
>   the working directory to match the HEAD commit.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I knew I could stash it, but was specifically concerned about what I described in the question. thanks.